# Setting textarea value in FF 4 no longer works...is it me or jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple  like this:

```
<textarea id="ind_comment" rows="4" cols="32"></textarea>
```

Then I have the following:
There is a hidden field and a button which has the class "showComment".  If there is a value in the hidden field the textarea should be populated with that value.

```
$(".showComment").click(function(){
    var rowid       = $(this).attr("rowid");
    var hiddenid    = "line_" + rowid + "_new_cmt";

    $("#ind_comment").val($("#line_" + rowid + "_new_cmt").val();

    var x = $(this).position().left + ($(this).outerWidth() -350);
    var y = $(this).position().top - $(document).scrollTop();

    $("#dialog").dialog({ 
        bgiframe: true,
        position: [x,y],
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        title: "Comments specific to this entry",
        modal: true,
        buttons: { "Close": function() { 
            $("#line_" + rowid + "_new_cmt").val($("#ind_comment").val());
            $("#ind_comment").val("");
            $(this).dialog("destroy"); 
        }}
    });
});
```

$("#ind_comment").val(""); clears the value as it should.

In FF4 (Windows or OS X)

```
$("#ind_comment").val(document.getElementById(hiddenid).value);
```

does not work but it works just fine in IE (tested with 8) and FF 3.x

I've also tried:

```
$("#ind_comment").val($("#line_" + rowid + "_new_cmt").val();
```

with no luck.

This is with jQuery 1.5.2

Am I missing something or is there an issue with FF4?

Here's a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mR2NQ/10/textarea)...It works the first time, but not the second time either of the buttons is clicked.

Comment: I just created a fiddle for FF4. This works, and I assume this wonky incremental rowid pattern has broken down on the OP, like it always will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that all the other examples left out the jquery dialog part...maybe that's where the issue is...?

While the jquery is a bit of a rat's nest why go through all the extra hoops?

1. Change the hidden input to a textarea
2. Wrap that textarea in it's own div
3. When the button is clicked turn that wrapped textarea into the dialog instead of using the one div as the text area

That way you avoid the need to swap the text in and out and such...

Might make it easier in the long run...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your incremental variable `id` pattern is terrible, and you should replace it with pulling the actual row number. Also, your variable naming is odd and against standard jQuery practices. Why do you set `element = $(this)`? That buys you nothing, and it's less descriptive than `$(this)` because you don't know you have a jQuery object. Also, you mix `document.getElementById` and `$('#')` for no reason.

Your code works, by the way.

Here's a [live test page](http://jsfiddle.net/mR2NQ/2/).

Comment: So I updated the code above.  I do the var rowid = $(this).attr("rowid"); only because the rows are not sequential in some cases.  I might have line_17_new_cmt line_1_new_cmt, line_2_new_cmt.  I added to your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mR2NQ/10/) and it works the first time clicked but it does not the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I have an identical problem.  old values are restored to textareas in jquery ui dialogs afer calling .dialog the second time.  This only occurs in Firefox 4 (current version is 4.0)

i think I have found a jquery UI bug ticket:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7239

Comment: To work around it I followed the idea in the accepted answer.  That did the trick for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same problem, there seems to be a bug with jQueryUI dialog 1.8 in a new Firefox.

Calling dialog('open') resets value for all textareas when using current Firefox5 version and possibly the latest versions of Firefox4 (client reported me this), while it works as expected in Chrome. Other inputs seem unaffected by this.

And this used to work in Firefox like 6 months ago, I'm positive about it, and not a line of javascript was changed since then on this project.